# Serializer doesn't return newly created related objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the POST request, I'm creating an instance of Item and then adding it to the FoodItem creation.
Returning from the post request I have `return Response(serializer.data)`
However, the FoodItem section is empty.
If I call a GET request on this new Item, I do get the FoodItem data.
Can I refresh the serializer after creating the FoodItem object?

```
class Item(models.Model):
        ITEMTYPE = (
            (1, 'Food'),
            (2, 'Clothes'),
            (3, 'Electronic')
        )
        itemType = models.IntegerField(choices=ITEMTYPE)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
        date_deleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.IntegerField()

class FoodItem(models.Model):
        item = models.OneToOneField(Item, blank=True)
        foodType = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
        calories = models.IntegerField()
```

My create code

```
def create(self, request, user_pk=None):
    data = request.data

    serializer = ItemSerializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    serializer.save()

    data['item'] = serializer.data['id']
    serializer2 = FoodItemSerializer(data=data)
    serializer2.is_valid()
    serializer2.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**EDIT: Serializers**

```
class FoodItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FoodItem
        fields = ('id','item','foodType','calories')

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    itemType_display = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_itemType_display')
    foodItem = FoodItemSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','itemType','itemType_display','description','date_created','date_modified','price','foodItem')
        read_only_fields = ['foodItem']
```

Comment: Actually this is not the right way to call .is_vaild(). Either use it like .is_valid(raise_exception=True) or check .is_vaild() in if condition then call .save() if .is_valid() returns True. If serialized is not saved properly then you cannot access serialized.data

Comment: Thanks. I just realized it.

Comment: So that solves the problem?

Comment: No, everything is valid and every is working. my only issue that serializer.data doesn't have the FoodItem values

Comment: But fooditem data is in seralizer2.data not in serializer.data..

Comment: Also make sure all seralizer.save() return corresponding instance..

Comment: But I did make sure ItemSerializer will return the information for FoodItem and it does return it on you do a GET request.

Comment: Please add code for both the serializers. Also, what fields are you sending in the `POST` request?

Comment: @RahulGupta I added the serializers. the post request has all the needed values for both objects.